# Java - pass object as parameter in constructor

Tags: java, parameters, constructor, cannot-find-symbol

My gaol is to use an instance of a class as parameter for another class. I will describe my problem with an example.

```
public class Color {

    public String color;
    public Color (String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
    public Color grey = new Color("grey");
}
```

My goal is to build another constructor that uses instances of my fist class as parameters (for example a car):

```
public class car {

    int PS;
    Color color;

    public Auto (int PS, Color color) {
        this.PS = PS;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        car myCar = new car(80, grey);
}
```

I get the error "Java cannot find symbol". I tried a lot but can't make it run and I don't fully understand the concepts of classes I guess.

Comment: You could use `Car myCar = new Car(80, new Color("grey"));` and then read more tutorials.

Comment: `public Color grey = new Color("grey");` will cause a `StackOverflowError`, because it's a member variable inside the `Color` class: to create a `Color`, you create a `Color`, which creates a `Color`, which creates a `Color`....

Comment: You have multiple issues here, and you should always post *the entire error message*--in this case, it shows you exactly where the unknown symbol is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your constructor name and your class name should be the same. `Auto` is not the same as `car`. Just change one of them. Also `grey` is not defined. I believe you want to use `Color.grey` which means defining it as `static`.

```
public class Color {

    public String color;
    public Color (String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
    public static Color grey = new Color("grey");
}

public class car {

    int PS;
    Color color;

    public car (int PS, Color color) {
        this.PS = PS;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        car myCar = new car(80, Color.grey);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `cannot find symbol` error usually means that it's a problem with *scope*--that is, what bits are visible where. In your case, `grey` is defined *on the class `Color`*, but you're trying to use it from `Car`. If you are trying to build a set of reusable `Color` objects, make `grey` `static final` (the `static` means that it belongs to *the entire class `Color`* and not to a specific color), and call it `GREY` to fit conventions.

Then, from your main method, you still won't see `GREY` because it's inside another scope. You can tell Java where to find it by calling it `Color.GREY`.

Comment: Thank you chrylis, very well explained.